# cypress run: keep test runner open

Tags: cypress

How can I run my `Cypress` tests using:

```
cypress run --headed
```

but keep the [test runner](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html#Overview) open at the end of the tests, like it is [using the Cypress Test Runner in interactive mode](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-open) (`cypress open`)?

I prefer `cypress run --headed` over `cypress open`, which require user interaction to launch the tests.

(The context in running the Cypress tests in continuous integration, but with `xvfb` and a `vnc` server, so the test runner can still be used once the tests are complete).

Comment: I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1871) for this feature, might be in by next patch release, considering it's just a cli change

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to run:
`cypress run --headed --no-exit`
As of version 3.0.2, the next patch release. See the [PR here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/1875)